# What's Normal Distribution Time for SSRN?

Tags: preprint

I've submitted two papers to the [Social Science Research Network (SSRN)](https://www.ssrn.com/index.cfm/en/). One paper was approved within a week and the other has been In Process for two weeks. This isn't problematic, but I'm curious about what normal time is and whether there are certain things I could do to expedite. I couldn't find information with quick googling.

Is anyone aware of data on SSRN distribution time, or on general preprint server distribution time?

Comment: What is SSRN? We're not very good with area-specific abbreviations here...

Comment: Great comment, thanks. I've updated the question to reflect that SSRN is the Social Science Research Network, a preprint server focused on social science. I've also noted that preprint server distribution time in general is welcome.